# What's the difference between `add al, 0` and `add al, '0'`?

Tags: assembly, instructions

So I've been reading some assembly code for learning purposes and have come across these two instructions:

```
add    register, value
add    register, 'value'     ; Where the value is now in single quotes
```

What's the difference between the two?

Before I get flamed if this happens to be a duplicate. I've asked here as I don't know exactly what to Google to answer this question.

Comment: `value` is the actual value. `'value'` is a character which represents an ASCII value (by "value" in your post I assume you mean a single digit). So `0` is zero. `'0'` is a value of 0x30 (the ASCII value of the character `'0'`).

Comment: Have you tried using `objdump` to see what the difference is?

Comment: @lurker - Ahh I assumed that. Just wanted to be extra sure. Thanks :)

Comment: The best source for syntax information is (usually) the used assembler documentation, for example [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.2) allows three ways of "quotes": `'0' "0" \`0\`` - the single and double quotes are the same thing, enclosing string (i.e. `'0123'` will be compiled into byte values `48 49 50 51`), backticks are similar, but will also parse C-like meta characters, i.e. `\`\n\`` will compile as value `10`. Other assemblers may vary wildly in their syntax. (and whenever not sure, check resulting machine code with `objdump` or use listing file from assembler)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending upon the assembler, enclosing a character in single quotes may request that the compiler use the ASCII code of that character, which for the digit zero would be 48 in decimal or 0x30 in hex.  I would guess that's the intention here.  Other assemblers use single quotes as part of the syntax for specifying values in different bases (e.g. h'A5' for the value 0xA5 in hex); I'm not sure whether assemblers that use such notation would interpret a value in quotes without a prefix would be interpreted as:

1. a number in the default base
2. a number in base ten even when the default is something else
3. a character code, or
4. a syntax error

Any of those interpretations would seem plausible, and I would not be terribly surprised if there's some assembler somewhere that would process it in each such fashion.

I would guess the intention of the code is most likely to take the ASCII value of the digit zero, and surrounding instructions would probably make that clear, but without seeing the context I can't really be sure.